# WordPress not loading CSS or JS

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Hi i am working on my client site I cannot figure out why resources like css/js/images are not loading. neither on the main site nor on the backend. I have replaced with new WP core files but still I cannot figure out the problem. here is the site: http://old.allsaintsnorthepping.org.au/
if you check the console it will say 404 not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a command line , then you need to change/set the permissions of the all the wordpress files and re-upload them to the server.

Run the following commands through terminal to change files and folders permission.

```
find folder_name -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find folder_name -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Replace folder_name with your wordpress folder.

Comment: I dont have cpanel access and I think all of my files are 644 and folders are 755 I can see from the FTP

Comment: Yes but you need to apply the permissions again , also try to set the permalink again , check the .htaccess file is writable , also add 
define('WP_HOME','http://old.allsaintsnorthepping.org.au');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://old.allsaintsnorthepping.org.au'); to wp-config.php at the top.

The reason I found is : http://old.allsaintsnorthepping.org.au/wp-content/themes/twenty-sixteen/images/logo.png

logo file isn't working , so I guess it is a permission issue or file haven't uploaded properly.